# What are your options when an exception occurs at Application.Run()?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm using a *great* library called [GreatMaps.NET](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) for doing some mapping in my application. I really love the library (and highly recommend it), but I occasionally get an unhandled ArgumentOutOfRangeException from one of the internal GreatMap.NET routines which bumps out all the way to my Program.Main().  Since there is no chance for my application to catch this error and handle it, am I just supposed to accept that this bug exists? Or, is there a way for me to prevent the problem?

I've included the call stack just in case it shows something I may be missing.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay.DrawRoutes(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay.Render(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaintOverlays(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at Spectrum.Foxhunt.Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Spectrum\Spectrum.Foxhunt.Client\Program.cs:line 23
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you added Unhandled Exception Handlers to your application?

Comment: do you know the condition you had to set so that this "bug" occurs?

Comment: @WiiMaxx Not a clue. This application runs 24/7. I've never "seen" it happen. It's always happened when the program has been unattended. Just sitting there.

Comment: maybe you could write a simple logger class which just saves the in/output for this so you are maybe able to find the conditions and than you can build an workaround

Comment: Have you checked if this still happens with the most current version of GreatMaps.NET? Based on your stack trace, you *appear* to be using an older version (but I'm not familiar with it, and I may be misreading)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how can you tell from the stack trace that I am using an older version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is definitly a bug in that library, one solution would be to create a class that derives from `GMapControl` and use that one instead of the original one.

In the derived class you would override `OnPaint` and catch that exception:

```
public class GMapControlFixed : GMapControl
{
    public override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            // discard - it's a bug in the original control.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to catch any unhandled exception, use it in your `static void Main()`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

And the event handler:

```
private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    //...
}
```

I use this for testing, to find strange bugs.

Comment: "Be sure to remove (-=) the event handler before exiting the application." - Why? There is no benefit in doing so.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: You're right - i mixed it up with the static events of the `Application` class, where the MSDN says:  `Because this is a static event, you must detach any event handlers attached to this event`

Comment: This works great with a logging library like log4net. I've just implemented it so that all unhandled exceptions will be logged into my log files. Will help me to debug once the program goes live.